# Replace a string containing colon, slash and apostrophe in all files with given pattern with dynamic bash script variable?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

How can I replace a string containing colon, slash and apostrophe in all files with given pattern with dynamic bash script variable?

I have several css files with strings like `src:url('/resource/` and I want to change these strings with `src:url('/resource/NS__` where `NS` is a literal value of $namespace bash script variable.

I tried to execute the following commands

```
find force-app -type f -name "*.css" -exec sed -i "s/src\:url('\/resource\/:/src\:url('\/resource\/$namespace__/g" {} \;
```

and this

```
find force-app -type f -name "*.css" -exec sed -i "" "s/src\:url('\/resource\/:/src\:url('\/resource\/$namespace__/g" {} \;
```

For the first command, I received the error

```
sed: 1: "force-app/main/default/ ...": invalid command code f
```

For the second command, I didn't receive any error but no changes were made

My local env is MacOs but my CI destination runs on ubuntu, so I need both version for Mac and Ubuntu working

Comment: No, it doesn't. My question is about escaping slash, backslash, colon in substitution script and that doesn't cover this

Comment: So, you just need to fix the `sed` command? `"s,src:url('/resource/,src:url('/resource/${namespace}__,g"`?

Comment: I have already figured this out, yes, I was asking about how can I fix the sed command in bash script

Comment: It seems to me the only real problem here is the need of `{}` to mark the variable, `${namespace}`.

Comment: I was escaping colon and slash, while I should have escaped the single quote, so that's why the script didn't work. Braces missing were not the only problem here

Comment: I have found the clues here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Comment: You do not need to escape `'` inside `"..."`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got it.

I need to escape single quote, but I don't need to escape colon or slash, so this command actually worked

```
find force-app -type f -name "*.css" -exec sed -i "" "s|src:url(\'/resource/|src:url(\'/resource/${namespace}__|g" {} \;
```

and this one should work on ubuntu

```
find force-app -type f -name "*.css" -exec sed -i  "s|src:url(\'/resource/|src:url(\'/resource/${namespace}__|g" {} \;
```